# Buffer depth of UART in Arm cortex M7 processor

Tags: c

Can any one tell me what is the buffer depth of Arm cortex M7 processor.Where can i find?Since i am net to the processor development?i need to know what is the buffer depth of UART in Arm Cortex M7 processor.

Comment: C language does not have any hardware buffers or UARTS and does not know anything about cortex M7 anyway. You should pick some more related tags for your question.

Comment: Please refer to your controller user manual!

Comment: Why do you need to know the depth of the UART buffers? It's very rare these days that boards don't come with some sort of Board Support Package to help get the hardware up and running. These usually contain simple drivers for all available hardware. You shouldn't have to write your own UART driver from scratch unless you really want to, and at least you will have an example to work from.

Comment: Cortex M7 is a core, so we don't know [what exactly CPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-M#Chips_6) you're using, and therefore can't provide a valid answer.

Comment: Should belong to https://electronics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Arm CORTEX micros do not have any uarts. Those ones are developed by the chip venfors, and every single vendor has its own design. UARTS do not have hardware buffers only FIFOs of the size 2 or 4 depending on the uart design and vendor.

Answer (score 0):

Microcontroller vendors design the UART part, ARM is only designing cortex -m core, NVIC (nested vectored interrupt controller) and some buses. One mcu vendor can put 1 byte uart buffer while another one can design it with 10 bytes fifo. That totally depends on the design of the mcu.